# Is Canon 550D the same model as Rebel T2i?

Tags: canon-550d

I keep hearing Rebel T2i. What does it mean? Isn't this just Canon 550D? I want to buy a Canon 550D but I get confused by Rebel 2Ti.

Comment: I've a Ti and a T1i, it's a very confusing naming system in the US ;)

Comment: A longer list of translations is available at http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2146/what-are-the-international-translations-for-canon-dslr-body-names

Comment: It is charted on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_550D and its *Canon EOS Digital SLR timeline* section.

Comment: WHY ON EARTH Canon have this crazy different naming convention I'll never understand! :)

Comment: Canon's damned naming system is ridiculous!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The exact same camera is sold as 550D in Europe, Rebel T2i in the US and (I think) KISS X4 in Japan

Answer (score 2):

The Canon EOS 550D is also known as Rebel T2i and Kiss X4 Digital.

The same camera is marketed under different names for each market.

According to wikipedia it is the EOS Kiss X4 in Japan and EOS Rebel T2i in North America.

see [dpreview](http://www.dpreview.com/previews/canoneos550d/) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/550D)