# Is Magic lantern compatible with Canon Kiss X5 (600D)

Tags: canon, canon-600d, magic-lantern

I purchased a new Canon camera last time in Thailand, this I was told really is an EOS 600D camera, but the Japanese version (Kiss X5) which I got for a pretty nice price,

Now I wonder if this camera is compatible with Magic Lantern?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the international translations for Canon DSLR body names?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2146/what-are-the-international-translations-for-canon-dslr-body-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. From [ML's webpages](http://www.magiclantern.fm/downloads.html):

Cameras supported:

- 5D Mark ii 2.1.2
- 50D 1.0.9
- 60D 1.1.1
- 500D 1.1.1
- 550D 1.0.9
- 600D 1.0.2