# Canon camera body names

Tags: canon, body

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the major differences between these camera series by Canon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/788/what-are-the-major-differences-between-these-camera-series-by-canon)

Right now I'm rocking a Canon Rebel XS and I get that there's some kind of progression from XS to T1, T2, T3 etc and I get the "i" variants (XSi, T3i, etc), but where I get confused is with the EOS 1D, EOS 5D, EOS 7D, EOS 60D, etc.

From what I can tell they seem to each lend themselves towards a particular niche of photography (one claims improved IR for stargazers), but I'm not sure what the others might be good for.

Can someone explain the differences in this models and maybe what certain features might be good for?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty much is a duplicate, but my Google-fu wasn't sufficient to get me there. *apologies*

Comment: No problem. The search function here isn't great, and even with a better search it's sometimes hard to know what to look for. Marking this as a duplicate will actually provide more pointers to the canonical answer, so it's all good.