# What Canon body can replace my (dead) dRebel and use the same lenses?

Tags: canon

My Canon EOS digital Rebel XT Body was bought used and then repaired and now is unreliable again.  It gets Err 99.  I have several lenses for it and want to continue to use them.   Which newer Canon body is compatible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between EF and EF-S lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the major differences between these camera series by Canon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/788/what-are-the-major-differences-between-these-camera-series-by-canon)

Comment: Err99 is usually a bad lens aperture.  Are you sure it isn't the lens?

Comment: @dgatwood, actually [Err99](http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/education/infobank/camera_settings/eos_error_codes_and_messages.do?page=2) is Canon's version of the BSoD. It's basically an unknown error. I got it when a power board went bad on my XT.

Comment: Gah.  I'm thinking of Err01.  Never mind.

Answer (score 4):

Any APS-C Canon EOS body, other than the D30 from the year 2000, the D60 from 2002 (not to be confused with the later 30D and 60D models introduced in 2006 and 2010, respectively), and the 10D released in 2003, is compatible with all EF and all EF-S lenses. The D30, D60, and 10D were APS-C format Canon EOS cameras that pre-existed the development of EF-S lenses.

You haven't said what lenses you have. If all of your lenses are EF lenses and none of them are EF-S lenses then *any* Canon EOS body ever made, film or digital, is compatible with them. Any EOS body is also compatible with the MP-E and TS-E series lenses.

The Canon APS-C series includes the following:

- 7D series, such as the 7D Mark II
- *x0D* series, such as the 80D
- *xx0D* series, such as the 400D or 800D
- *xx00D* series, such as the 1300D

The *xx0D* and *xx00D* series are marketed in the U.S. as the *Digital Rebel* line.